# How to start a live server with VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, server, live

I am new to web development and coding. For convenience I installed Live Server 5.6.1 for VS Studio and for my chrome extension. When I want to start a live server and load my html file, another page is loaded into my browser with the following content:

[Webpage Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMgT9.jpg)

Comment: Hi @Tobias, are you in the correct directory?

Comment: Is there a default directory from where I have to start the html-file? Where is the directory?

Comment: there is no `index.html` file in the directory you open in vscode, so Live Server offers you to choose the file you need.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` from the current directory.

This would serve the current directory tree for access.

eg. 
`pwd` shows `/Users/username` so running here,

```
$ python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

will load contents of this directory on your accessible browser.